# Creating argument variable

Tags: ruby, argv

I tested the code below:

```
cheese, apple, bread = ARGV

puts "The script is called: #{$0}"
puts "Your first variable is: #{cheese}"
puts "Your second variable is: #{apple}"
puts "Your third variable is: #{bread}"
```

I get empty outputs for line 2-4:

```
The script is called: /run_dir/repl.rb
Your first variable is: 
Your second variable is: 
Your third variable is:
```

It's not the expected result. I could not quite figure out what I am doing wrong. Could anyone give me a hand? What could be the reason for that?

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Your code is correct. Try running your script like this: `ruby /run_dir/repl.rb first second third`

Comment: @SebastiánPalma:I was running it on REPL.IT website IDE.

Comment: @R.Gadeev: I tried to run the code you recommended and tried "ruby /run_dir/repl.rb cheese apple bread" ; both gave me the error code "(repl):9: unknown regexp options - rpl" , the "/run_dir/repl" part was in red. I am  not sure it was supposed to be in red, or it cannot find that directory from the cloud.

Comment: repl.it is an online interpreter, try instead in your local machine, or if you can't consider using [c9.io](http://c9.io/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The code works just fine. Did you actually pass command line arguments to the script? Which ones? How? Which shell are you using? Does your shell even support passing command line arguments? Does it require them to be escaped or marked somehow? How, *exactly* are you executing the script?

Comment: @DilAzat your actual question seems to be _"how to set command line arguments in repl.it?"_.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma: I tried c9, same thing, The script is called: /home/ubuntu/workspace/rubyfirst.rb
Your first variable is called: 
YOur second variable is  called: 
Your third variable is called:

Comment: Did you do `/home/ubuntu/workspace/rubyfirst.rb a b c`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma; I could say that as well; maybe because I am new to this type of coding, had a hard time to figure out my mistake. Thank you for your prompt replies! :)

Comment: Don't worry, thank also every person who invested time helping you.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I knew it was me making some mistake somewhere. I got it to work now thanks to all of your help :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`cheese, apple, bread = ARGV` is the equivalent to say `ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]` just in the first one you're storing every parameter passed at the moment in which you run your script, that's why if you're getting a `NilClass` object is because you're not using or setting parameters when you run the script.

Try this time running it as `/run_dir/repl.rb cheese apple bread` to get values for those variables initialized as `ARGV`.

Comment: I used this code, but slightly changed the directory, it's working now. This had been really helpful. Thank you!